# mysql---database size

Tags: mysql

why the number of the database size bigger than the  number of the database size which i download to the local environment.(i export the dabase by the phpmyadmin's export button)

Comment: i extract the dabase by the phpmyadmin's export button. the database is created by a CMS

Comment: are you sure, you aren't using any compressing method (like gzip etc.)

Comment: yes,i am sure, i didn't use any compressing method.

Comment: are you comparing  the downloaded file with you database import or the original database in the server to your database in the local environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, [phpmyadmin shrinks the database by 1/3](http://drupal.org/node/81993) some said in a post dated back February 25, 2010 at 6:12am.

If you want to be sure the data is the same, do the following the next time you export:

1. Collect all table names in the database before the export.
2. Generate a checksum for all the tables and put the tablename and checksum value in DBCheckSum1.txt
3. Load the exported data into another instance of mysql
4. Collect all table names in the second database
5. Generate a checksum for all the tables and put the tablename and checksum value in DBCheckSum2.txt
6. Compare the Checksum Files